# Miscalculation of big floating point numbers in Gcc, Python and Google calculator

Tags: python, c, gcc, floating-point

Why the result of these two expressions should be different ?
The same thing happens in gcc and python. what is happening in here ? Is there any way to prevent it ?
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Floating point numbers have limited precision. If you add a small number (3) to a large number (1e20), the result often is the same as the large number. That is the case here, hence

```
(3 + 1e20) - 1e20 = 1e20 - 1e20 = 0
```

The precision of `double` is roughly 15 decimal digits, `float`s have about 7 decimal digits of precision.

Comment: +1; in Python at least you can do `(3 + int(1e20)) - int(1e20)` and get `3`.

Answer (score 3):

Although it's related to timestamps, the article [“Don't store that in a float”](http://altdevblogaday.com/2012/02/05/dont-store-that-in-a-float/) gives a rough overview of the pitfalls you can get when using floating point arithmetics, most importantly:

> This real example demonstrates a few things:
>
> - Any time you add or subtract floats of widely varying magnitudes you need to watch for loss of precision
> - Sometimes using ‘double’ instead of ‘float’ is the correct solution, but often a more stable algorithm is more important

In your second case you're adding 10²⁰ to 3, which *is* a widely varying magnitude. Due to the limited precision of doubles (14 digits approx, 7 for four byte floats (single precision)), the 3 will just get lost in the result. If you however first subtract 10²⁰ from itself, you get a zero, which added to 3 does not change the result at all.

These slight difference in operation ordering can become important in certain calculations and is a thing one should always bear in mind when dealing with floating point numbers on IEEE platforms. A simulation which ran fine for hours suddenly breaking without any reason or only when something specific happens can easily be caused by floating point arithmetics.